# ROS Node to Node time duration

Tags: c++, ros

how can I figure out how much time it takes to send a message from one node to the other? is there a function or a c++ node example to use as a test scenario for this ?

Comment: You would probably have better luck at: http://answers.ros.org/questions/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your application and on the accuracy you want to achieve: it could vary as a stochastic process in multi-thread environment.

However, you can have a rough estimation using `pre_publish_time_ = ros::Time::now()` just before the `publish()` call and computes the elapsed time in the subscriber callback as `ros::Time elapsed_time = ros::Time::now() - pre_publish_time_`, where `pre_publish_time_` is a `ros::Time` member variable.

If publisher and subscriber lay in different classes you can add the [std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) in you message and use the `header.stamp` field as `pre_publish_time_` (properly filled just before the `publish()` method as said above).

[geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Vector3Stamped.html) Example:

```
void publishFcn() {
  // ...

  geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped msg;
  msg.vector.x = 0;
  msg.vector.y = 0;
  msg.vector.z = 1;
  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  publisher_.publish(msg);
}

void msgCallback(const geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped &msg) {
  ros::Time elapsed_time = ros::Time::now() - msg.header.stamp;

  // ...
}
```